# Trouble setting up Raknet Server on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi2, raknet

I have been trying to get Raknet up and running on my Raspberry Pi (2).

I am using a simple client server test program to connect from my windows machine to my raspberry pi. Using tshark on the Pi I can see that all message are arriving on the Pi. However, the server application does not seem to pick those up. As far as I can deduce all ports are open, the machines are on the same network, the code is correct (taken from some github repo with examples for raknet).

The frustrating thing is that a while back I though I solved this communication by starting my server app as root (sudo). However, in the meantime something has been changed in my setup which makes this no longer the case. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: BTW the sample comes from the RakNet GitHub repo itself.

Comment: Try asking your question at https://www.slikesoft.com/forum/ and see if anyone can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot about my question here. It actually had to do with privileges on the networks we use here. I had been testing on two different networks without realizing. Problem has been solved.